# How do I speed up my python scripts using multithreading or multiprocesses

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python script for text comparison, simple calculation, the number of samples involved is relatively large and need to use loops possible, and now I want to use multithreading for acceleration.

This script is mainly used to merge blast output results, extract gene locus information according to ORF files, and count the number of MGE gene occurrences.
Here is my existing script want to use multithreading acceleration in Ubuntu systems：

```
#!/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/args_oap/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import concurrent.futures
import time
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys

# path to blast-annotation result
folder_path = '/media/ubuntu/data/tianli/mining_data/ARG_risk_assessment/test'

#get .txt file
files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.txt')]

#create new frame to solve data
all_data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_path, file), sep='\t', header=None)
    
    #remove .txt
    filename = file[:-4]
    
    #split file name
    sample_name, annotation_type = filename.rsplit('_', 1)
    
    #add new col
    data.insert(0, 'sample_name', sample_name)
    data.insert(1, 'annotation_type', annotation_type)
    data.insert(2, 'contig', data[0].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[0])
    
    #add data in frame
    all_data = pd.concat([all_data, data])

#add col name
all_data.columns = ['sample_name', 'annotation_type', 'contig', 'contig_orf', 'sequence_id', 'pident', 'alignment_length', 'mismatch', 'gap_openings', 'query_start', 'query_end', 'subject_start', 'subject_end', 'evalue', 'bitscore']

#
#

all_data['bac_name'] = ''
all_data['bac_id'] = ''
all_data['bac_pathogen'] = ''

patonlist = pd.read_csv('/media/ubuntu/data/tianli/mining_data/2434_pathon_list.txt', sep='\t', header=None)

unique_samples = all_data['sample_name'].unique()

def process_sample (sample):
    sample_r = sample.replace('-', '_')
    out_file = pd.read_csv(f'/media/ubuntu/data/tianli/mining_data/contig-kraken/{sample_r}.out', sep='\t', header=None)
    report_file = pd.read_csv(f'/media/ubuntu/data/tianli/mining_data/contig-kraken/{sample_r}.report', sep='\t', header=None)

    for index, row in all_data.iterrows():

        if row['sample_name'] == sample:

            matching_rows1 = out_file[out_file[1] == row['contig']]
            print(f"sample: {row['sample_name']}")
            print(f"contig: {row['contig']}")

            if not matching_rows1.empty:

                all_data.loc[index, 'bac_id'] = matching_rows1.iloc[0, 2]
                print(f"bac_id : {all_data.loc[index, 'bac_id'].iloc[0]}")

            matching_rows2 = report_file[report_file[4] == row['bac_id']]

            if not matching_rows2.empty:

                all_data.loc[index, 'bac_name'] = matching_rows2.iloc[0, 5].strip()
            print(f"bac_name : {all_data.at[index, 'bac_name'].iloc[0]}")

            matching_rows3 = patonlist[patonlist[1] == row['bac_name']]

            if not matching_rows3.empty:

                all_data.loc[index, 'bac_pathogen'] = matching_rows3[0].values[0]
            else:

                all_data.loc[index, 'bac_pathogen'] = 'NO'
            print(f"bac_pathogen : {all_data.at[index, 'bac_pathogen'].iloc[0]}")
    
    
    #
    #
    all_data['orf_start'] = ''
    all_data['orf_end'] = ''
    all_data['orf_head'] = ''
    all_data['orf_location'] = ''
    # all_data['5kbp_mge_num'] = 0

    for sample in all_data['sample_name'].unique():

    # ORF文件
        orf_records = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(f'/media/ubuntu/data/tianli/mining_data/megahit_prodigal_orf/{sample}_pro.fa', 'fasta'))

        sample_rows = all_data[all_data['sample_name'] == sample]

        for index, row in sample_rows.iterrows():

            orf_record = orf_records[row['contig_orf']]

            annotations = orf_record.description.split('#')
            print(f"orf information: {annotations}")

            all_data.loc[index, 'orf_start'] = annotations[1].strip()
            all_data.loc[index, 'orf_end'] = annotations[2].strip()
            all_data.loc[index, 'orf_head'] = annotations[3].strip()
            all_data.loc[index, 'orf_location'] = (int(annotations[2]) + int(annotations[1])) / 2

        #mge

        rows_A = all_data[(all_data['sample_name'] == sample) & (all_data['annotation_type'] == 'arg')]

        rows_B = all_data[(all_data['sample_name'] == sample) & (all_data['annotation_type'] == 'mge')]

        for index_A, row_A in rows_A.iterrows():

            same_contig_rows_B = rows_B[rows_B['contig'] == row_A['contig']]

            if any(np.abs(same_contig_rows_B['orf_location'] - row_A['orf_location']) <= 5000):

                all_data.loc[index_A, '5kbp_mge_num'] += 1

                
#time start
start_time = time.time()

#multy threads
#with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(process_sample, unique_samples)

#time use
end_time = time.time()
print(f"Running time : {end_time - start_time} seconds")   

#save result             
all_data.to_csv('all_annotation_pathon_mge-num_arg-info.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
```